# Can Someone Help Me Fix This Code - Eclipse Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

my app is open as usual, but when I click in the TextPlay section the follow message appears: "Unfortunately, (app name) has stopped."
I don't know what to do anymore, please, somebody help me!!!

The Error Log in Console:

> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vhcorrea.test1/com.vhcorrea.test1.TextPlay}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at com.vhcorrea.test1.TextPlay.onCreate(TextPlay.java:24)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
>
> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069):    ... 11 more

My TextPlay.java:

```
package com.vhcorrea.test1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class TextPlay extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);
    
    final Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
    final ToggleButton passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Commands);
    final TextView  display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
    passTog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(passTog.isChecked()){
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            }else{
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

            }
        }
        
    });
    chkCmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String check = input.getText().toString();
        display.setText(check);
        if (check.contentEquals("left")) {
            display.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        }else if (check.contentEquals("center")) {
            display.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }else if (check.contentEquals("right")) {
            display.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }else if (check.contentEquals("green")) {
            display.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }else if (check.contains("WTF")) {
            
        }else{
            display.setText("invalid");
            display.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }


        }
    });
}
}
```

Everybody has said that errors may be found in the Manifest, but I don't think so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.vhcorrea.test1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.vhcorrea.test1.MainActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
                  
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.vhcorrea.test1.MENU" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    
    <activity
        android:name=".TextPlay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.vhcorrea.test1.TEXTPLAY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      </application>
```

Comment: obviously, view with id `R.id.Commands` is not an `EditText`

Comment: please post also the activity.xml

Comment: you should post the xml file along this code as it clearly indicates there is an error with edittext

Answer (score 2):

> 12-01 18:36:52.065: E/AndroidRuntime(3069): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be
>   cast to android.widget.EditText

```
final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Commands);
```

`R.id.Commands` is a `LinearLayout` not an `EditText`. That
is the reason for the `ClassCastException`.
Keep sure that you use the correct id of the `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

See check once your  text.xml file and see id of command. according to your error you cast linear layout to edit text

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.text);

final Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
final ToggleButton passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
final LinearLayout input = (LinearLAyout) findViewById(R.id.Commands);
final TextView  display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
```

because you didn't update your xml file so i am gussing. once update it. so i will be sure that where is error